# javascript date sort by Matt Kruse not sorting correctly

Tags: php, javascript, tablesorter

Hi: I just noticed something, well a client noticed it and I can't figure our the fix.

We are using a table/date sorter  Matt Kruse (javascripttoolbox.com).

it works perfectly, or so we thought, but a client just noticed that because the dates are extending into 2013, it is not sorting correctly.  See example below:

- 01/09/2013
- 01/10/2013
- 01/11/2013
- 07/17/2012
- 09/19/2012
- 09/25/2012
- 10/03/2012
- 10/05/2012
- 10/08/2012
- 10/08/2012

The above is in descending order, but it should pick the highest/most recent date in 2013 and come down from there.  Then when it gets to 2012, it should start with October and work it's way down.  But as you can see it does not

is anyone familiar with [Matt Kruse (javascripttoolbox dot com)] date sort script and what could/should be adjusted.  I have gone to his site and the code appears to be the same.

Comment: looks like this : http://javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/examples.php

Comment: Yes that the exact example.  If you sort the date table asc/desc they are in the correct order, but it does not happen with my data and I just copied the script into my site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the underlying data that you are trying to sort is a String and not a Date.  Therefore the sort is in alphabetical order.

You should double-check your data and make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving the Date table header the correct class name?

If the plugin doesn't see "date" in the class name it won't parse the column data correctly.

```
<th class="table-sortable:date">Date</th>
```